# Filenotfound Exception after resizing .png image

Tags: java, android, image, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

i have an .png image so according to my requirment changed the size, but now in the logcat i'm getting filenotfound exception even though the image is in asset folder, and also there is no capital letter, spaces between it. i could not make out why this occurs any idea?

```
// background layer: another image
            CCSprite background = CCSprite.sprite("shipe150.png");
            // scale the image (optional)
            background.setScale(1.5f);
            // change the transform anchor point (optional)
            background.setAnchorPoint(CGPoint.make(0,0));
```

logcat error

```
07-13 10:59:07.928: W/System.err(3017): java.io.FileNotFoundException: shipe150.png
07-13 10:59:07.928: W/System.err(3017):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
07-13 10:59:07.939: W/System.err(3017):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:315)
07-13 10:59:07.939: W/System.err(3017):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:289)
```

Comment: can you post relevant snippet of code?

Comment: show us some code ...........

Comment: I have never used Cocos2d. The logcat is comtempling about assets . Do you have shipe150.png inside the assets folder?

Comment: yes i have that image in asset folder @blackbelt

Comment: just check the name of the image cz setScale is not giving the error ...

Comment: Try `Project -> Clean` (or) restart the eclipse!

Comment: Have you got the answer or ... ?

Comment: no not yet. if i use the same .png image in other project i'm able to run it but not in this project @user26534

Comment: May be , there are two images with the same name is in Assets